# Can a function have equal maximum and minimum value?

Tags: maxima-minima

When I heard that the maximum value can be smaller than the minimum  value,  it striked me whether they can both be equal. I want to enquire whether it is true.

Comment: For a trivial example, consider any constant function.

Comment: For a simple example when $f_{max}=f_{min}$, see my Edit in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

### (A) $\bf 1$ Variable function :

It is possible that (*minima $\leq$ maxima*) **OR** (*minima $>$ maxima*), though these will be a **different points** on the curve.
Pictorially, we can see that here :

[image: Minima Maxima]

In the above graph as you can see, we have a minima at point $A$ and for each of the $3$ different purple curves, we have a point $B$ where $\bf \text{Maxima}>\text{or}=\text{or}<\text{Minima}$ (from top to bottom respectively).

### (B) $\bf 2$ Variable functions :

In this case, in addition to earlier cases, it is **possible** that the **same point** is **both** a **Minima** & a **Maxima**!  
Consider the following function:
$$\bf z=x^2-y^2$$
At $(x,y)=(0,0)$ , we have $z=0$ which is a **minima** when **considering** Variable $\bf x$ & a **maxima** when **considering** variable $\bf y$.
Such Points are known as "*Saddle Points*" or "*MiniMax Points*" ([more details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point)) & are very common.

[image: MiniMax Point]

Answer (score 1):

If there are several local maxima   and local minima then one local max being less than one local min is ordinary.

However, in case $f(x)$ has single  local max and single local min, then the situation of  $f_{max}\le f_{min}$ is more interesting as it implies that there is a discontinuity in the function in $(x_{max}, x_{min})$. For example:

$f(x)=\frac{(x-2)^2}{x-3}$, $f_{max}=f(2)=0$ and $f_{min}=f(4)=4$
see below
[image]

**EDIT** An example for $f_{max}=f_{min}$
$$f(x\le 0)=1-(x+2)^2, f(x>0)=1+(x+2)^2$$ as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about local maxima and minima, then it's definitely possible. As a simple example, check out $y = x (x-1)^2 (x+1)^2$:

[image]

This has a local minimum at $(1, 0)$ and a local maximum at $(-1, 0)$, in addition to its two other extrema.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it the wrong way around - local maximum at $(-1, 0)$ and local minimum at $(1, 0)$. Meaning that $0$ is both a maximum and minimum value at different points of the function.